# How to pass selected brand from drop down to controller in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is how i am rendering drop down for brands.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <select 
        ng-options="brand.id as brand.name for brand in brands"
        ng-model="selectedBrand"
        ng-change="update(selectedBrand);">
        <option value="">Select Brand</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

On change I want to call update function. This is update function in controller.

```
 $scope.update = function(selectedBrand){
    alert ($scope.selectedBrand.name);
    alert (selectedBrand.id);
}
```

But both the alert give me undefined.

How to pass selected brand properly, so I can get that in controller?

Comment: Related/Dup [AngularJS ng-options get selected item as an object](//stackoverflow.com/q/25974045), [AngularJS get selected item in scope](//stackoverflow.com/q/29486250)

Comment: try`brand.name as brand for brand in brands`

Comment: try printing just `$scope.selectedBrand`. I hope it will help :)

Answer (score 1):

try this--

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <select 
        ng-options="brand as brand.name for brand in brands"
        ng-model="selectedBrand"
        ng-change="update(selectedBrand);">
        <option value="">Select Brand</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

and in the controller

```
scope.selectedBrand={};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-app="optionsApp" ng-controller="optionsController as vm">
    <select ng-options="p.brand  for p in vm.brands" 
            ng-model="vm.selectedBrand">
    </select>
    <p>You selected {{vm.selectedBrand.brand}} 
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/kgtramps/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is what your html *(using `ng-options="brand.id as brand.name for brand in brands"`)* looks like after rendering.

see the value of the options its the id property of the objects, *EX: if you select one option then the value pass to the function is the id of the selected object*.

---

If you need to get the selected value as object then you have to change the `ngOptions` directive as below. *(This will select the name property of the object as the option text and the object as the value of the option.)*

[image]

```
<select ng-options="brand as brand.name for brand in brands" 
    ng-model="selectedBrand" ng-change="update(selectedBrand)">
    <option value="">Select Brand</option>
</select>
```

here is a [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/cyrs5wsndRMlKehddwv3?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('main', []);
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.chooseCountries=[
    {countryId : 1, name : "India", desc: "some description" },
    {countryId : 2, name : "USA", desc: "some description"},
    {countryId : 3, name : "Australia", desc: "some description"}
];   

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl" ng-app="main">
  <select ng-model="selectedCountry">
<option value="">Select Account</option>
      <option ng-repeat="x in chooseCountries" value="{{x.countryId}}"  >{{x.name}}</option>
</select>  
  <br/>
 Id: {{selectedCountry}} 
    <br/>
 Name: {{chooseCountries[selectedCountry-1].name.toString()}}
</div>
```